# Using selectors like jQuery on custom objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, phantomjs, casperjs

I am working on some casperjs scripts, and there I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "element": {
            "attributes": {
                "href": "http://google.com",
                "rel": "google"
            },
            "html": "link1",
            "nodeName": "a",
            "tag": "<a href=\"http://google.com\" rel=\"google\">link1</a>",
            "text": "link1"
        }
    },
    {
        "element": {
            "attributes": {
                "class": "someclass",
                "href": "http://yahoo.com",
                "id": "yahooid"
            },
            "html": "yahoo anchor",
            "nodeName": "a",
            "tag": "<a href=\"http://yahoo.com\" id=\"yahooid\" class=\"someclass\">yahoo anchor</a>",
            "text": "yahoo anchor
        }
    }
]
```

For some tasks I need to accomplish using these links it would be useful if I could select them using jQuery-like selectors.

I kinda have an idea how I could code something like that, but working on all the regex for all the type of selectors ([name|=”value”], [name*=”value”], [name~=”value”], [name$=”value”], etc) give me nightmares.

What is the simplest way i could achieve this?

Comment: Create a `div`, add tags based on the list of elements you have... use `jquery`

Comment: You just want the anchor tag links?? from this object array?

Comment: Your array of objects looks like Dom elements that you did something weird to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
function select( selector ) {
    var whitespace = "[\\x20\\t\\r\\n\\f]",
    identifier = "(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\0-\\xa0])+",
    attributes = "\\[" + whitespace + "*(" + identifier + ")(?:" + whitespace + "*([*^$|!~]?=)" + whitespace + "*(?:\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\"))" + whitespace + "*\\]",
    elFound = [];

    try {
        links.forEach( function(link) {
            expr = new RegExp( attributes );
            match = expr.exec( selector );
            attribute = match[1];
            operator = match[2];
            value = match[3];
            check = ( attribute == 'text' ) ? link.element[attribute] : link.element.attributes[attribute];

            switch( operator ) {
                    case "=":
                          if( check && check == value ) { elFound.push( link ); }
                          break;
                    case "!=":
                          if( check && check != value ) { elFound.push( link ); }
                          break;
                    case "*=":
                          if( check && check.indexOf( value ) > -1 ) { elFound.push( link ); }
                          break;
                    case "^=":
                          if( check && check.indexOf( value ) === 0 ) { elFound.push( link ); }
                          break;
                    case "$=":
                          if( check && check.slice( -value.length ) == value ) { elFound.push( link ); }
                          break;
                    default:
                          break;
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    return elFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to Just get the anchor tag links from the array of object, then this might help out. Also note in your OP the last element has a error `"text": "yahoo anchor` there is a closing `"` missing. Hope this is a typo from you.

```js
var objArray = [
    {
        "element": {
            "attributes": {
                "href": "http://google.com",
                "rel": "google"
            },
            "html": "link1",
            "nodeName": "a",
            "tag": "<a href=\"http://google.com\" rel=\"google\">link1</a>",
            "text": "link1"
        }
    },
    {
        "element": {
            "attributes": {
                "class": "someclass",
                "href": "http://yahoo.com",
                "id": "yahooid"
            },
            "html": "yahoo anchor",
            "nodeName": "a",
            "tag": "<a href=\"http://yahoo.com\" id=\"yahooid\" class=\"someclass\">yahoo anchor</a>",
            "text": "yahoo anchor"
        }
    }
]

$(function(){
   $.each(objArray,function(i,v){      
     var link = this.element.attributes.href ;
     $('div').append(link  + '<br/>');
     
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>


</div>
```